# Graph of large data set of 5 billion records

Tags: charts

I have a csv file of more than 5 billion entries in it.
I want to create a line or area chart for this data.
Which software I can use to do so.

The file size is 34GB.

Comment: [Software recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be an on-topic site for this.

Comment: @fixer1234 Software Recommendations moderator here. We have fairly strict quality requirements, so I'd appreciated it if you would link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) whenever you recommend someone re-ask a question on the site. Thanks!

Comment: No worries @fixer1234 :)

Comment: Do you want to pay for the software? Do you need to do the task only once or regularly? E.g. Spotfire, Mathematica, R can probably manage this amount of data.

Comment: R turns out to be really slow for this process